# printf with %s handling character arrays

Tags: c, linux, gcc

EDIT: My real intention is to find out what probably makes this work, where it shouldn't have.

The below program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    char name[5] = {'N', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'S'};
    int y = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    printf("%s:%x:%x\n", name, x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

simply works fine. Variables x and y were added to make sure there are non null characters before and after the string. They are also printed to make sure that printf() is used instead of puts(). gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4. I have checked the disassembly to make sure that the character array has non-null things around it.

The expectation was that as there are no '\0' present in the character array, printf() with %s would go on printing until it finds a 0 somewhere and hence there would be some garbage characters printed. But I see none. Does printf() handle the strings some different way? is '\0' no longer required?

Comment: So you are trying to get a definition for what Undefined Behaviour should do?

Comment: *Variables x and y were added to make sure there are non null characters before and after the string.* - This is not correct. The compiler can shift stuff about to make its life easier. It may even remove the need for variables

Comment: I have tried with 4 bytes. I have checked the assembly, before I added the x and y variables.

Comment: If you try to print a character array as a string, and the array does not end with a zero, you *will* have undefined behavior no matter how "fine" it seems to work.

Comment: Try `printf( "0x%x", names[5] );` to see what data is past the end of the "string".  That's still undefined behavior, but sometimes you get lucky...

Comment: As per standards, It is undefined behavior, but at least in gcc, this works fine.

Comment: @subin *As per standards, It is undefined behavior, but at least in gcc, this works fine.*  For **NOW**.  With this *simple* program.  Use an 8-character "string" and see what happens.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, tried with 4 and 8. Both works

Comment: @subin No, it doesn't "work".  It just doesn't crash or do anything visibly wrong.  There's a huge difference between that and "working", and if you want to write reliable code you'll try to understand that difference.

Comment: I agree, but my real intention is to find out what probably makes this work without printing any garbage characters.

Comment: It really has been pointed out to you multiple times. Your assumptions of the memory layout are likely incorrect and your analysis of the assembly is also likely incorrect. In your case, there is almost certainly a 0 somewhere by chance that is terminating the string.

Comment: [sigh] @subin if you want to know exactly what is going on with your flavour of UB, (presumably because that's what your homework question asks for), run your program under your debugger on your system, with your environment etc, and step through it, checking the values and layout of variables and dumping appropriate memory locations, and find your for yourself.  NOBODY ELSE can help you with that because they have a different system and different environment.  YOU have to do the work, sorry.

Comment: @kaylum that's correct, [I can confirm such reordering on my GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36646967/918959)

Comment: @MartinJames It totally does make sense, but you don't have to assume it is a homework question or assignment. People with less understanding of all the underlying concepts can still get curious even long after stop being a student (sigh)

Comment: @kaylum I understand. The only thing I was trying to find out, may be my question was asked in a wrong way, whether GCC (it is tagged GCC, and version mentioned), would handle this by any way. I got the same result on multiple x86 systems with same binary. Undefined behavior by standards doesn't mean a certain compiler should generate truly undefined behavior. It can decide to do things in its own way when there are no concerns. And GCC AFAIK, has many extension. I will check the hex dump.

Answer (score 5):

No, that doesn't "work fine".

It invokes undefined behavior since it passes a non-terminated string to `printf()`'s `%s` format specifier. The termination is required.

You can't assume things about where in memory local variables are stored; you can perhaps dump the memory around `name`, preferably using a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

`char name[5] = {'N', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'S'};` is not null-terminated. Printing such a char array with `printf("%s", name)` has **undefined behaviour**. Your program is not a strictly standard-conforming program.

You can add `'\0'` at the end and have defined behaviour:

```
char name[] = {'N', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'S', '\0'};
```

---

The C11 standard draft n1570 defines the undefined behaviour as:

> **1 Undefined behavior**
>
> Behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or
>   of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no
>   requirements
>
> **2 NOTE**
>
> Possible  undefined  behavior  ranges  from 
>   **ignoring  the  situation  completely  with  unpredictable results**, to
>   behaving during translation or program execution in a documented
>   manner characteristic of the environment  (with  or  without  the 
>   issuance  of  a  diagnostic  message),  to  terminating  a 
>   translation  or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

The unpredictable results mean that it can also **work fine**, depending on the day. Or perhaps cause demons fly out of your nose. The only lesson to be learned from this is that in C the statement "it works, therefore it is right" is not quite true.

---

In comments you said that even if you changed the program to use

```
char name[8] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'};
```

It still wouldn't print garbage. The reason why you're confused is because you make incorrect assumptions about the variable layout in memory. I did the above change and added the statement:

```
printf("x at %p, name at %p, y at %p", (void*)&x, (void*)&name, (void*)&y);
```

and got the output

```
x at 0x7ffdbfde5408, name at 0x7ffdbfde5410, y at 0x7ffdbfde540c
```

From this it is clear that the compiler optimized the 32-bit ints into same 8-byte stack slot (stack pointer must be 8-byte aligned on x86-64) and moved the char array above **both of these canary values** in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, your code invokes undefined behaviour.
Using gcc (version 5.3.0 on 64bit OS X 10.11), I found the reason that it still works to be that the `name` array on the stack is aligned to 8 bytes (natural size of a 64bit system), and the other three bytes just happen to be null bytes.

Changing your array to include 8 characters, like so:

```
char name[8] = {'N', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'S', '1', '2', '3'};
```

gave me the following output:

> NAMES123��������:ffffffff:ffffffff

So this doesn't "work fine". You just got lucky.

First of all, your compiler could nuke you (both metaphorically and literally, actually), because undefined behaviour. It's very generous of it not to do so.

And second, there is always a possibility for your array to end up in a place next to a null byte. But if you play around with it long enough, you're very likely to hit a case where it doesn't and you get some garbage printed out.

Comment: for me, even the size 8 worked. on a 32 bit system. With the declaration as you have mentioned.

Comment: Well, lucky you. You'll have to look at the generated assembly if you want to know the aligned size for sure, but I'm pretty sure it's gonna be a power of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already explained that this is undefined behavior. As to your *actual* question about *why* it "works": aligning.

The compiler is aligning the variables so their addresses start on multiples of the processor's word size. IIRC, this speeds up access. Assuming you're on a 64-bit CPU, this means the compiler will align to 8-byte addresses (unless explicitly told not to).

The padding space is usually filled with zeros. So the memory will likely look like this here:

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
-------------------------------
'N' 'A' 'M' 'E' 'S'  0   0   0   <--- "name"
 FF  FF  FF  FF  0   0   0   0   <--- maybe "y" is here
```

So the string is *implicitly* null terminated. But there is nothing guaranteeing this behavior. The padding could be any garbage character. And as soon as no padding is taking place or the string size is a multiple of the word size, you might get garbage or even a segmentation fault.

In short: it "works" due to sheer luck in your case. You *cannot* rely on this to continue working in the future or on any other system than the one you are currently using, with the specific compiler options you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The space for name is padded on the stack to a 4 or 8 byte boundary. However, it is not guaranteed behaviour that the extra space always has to be zero filled. In the example this is most likely due to the state of the stack at the invocation of main.

In short: This works only by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior is undefined. "Seems to work just fine" is one case of undefined behavior. Usually it is not meaningful practice to investigate why undefined behavior ended up in a certain way, there is typically nothing valuable to learn from it.

One reason why it might work by accident is that your compiler likes to align data to 8 bit boundaries. Looking at the memory dump of your program from GCC  Windows 7 64-bit, I get this:

```
0x22fe40: 4e 41 4d 45 53 00 00 00|ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    
0x22fe50: b0 1f 45 00 00 00 00 00|b5 13 40 00 00 00 00 00
```

In this case the array was allocated at address 0x22fe40 and the integers from 0x22fe48. By luck, there happens to be zeroes at the end of the array, so by luck it could be treated as a string this time.

Next time the program is executed/compiled/ported you might not be so lucky.